# plugin value in a template conditional

Tags: conditionals, plugin

I've frequently done this with success:

```
{if '{exp:my_plugin:my_method}'}My method returned true{/if}
```

Or the opposite also works:

```
{if '{exp:my_plugin:my_method}' == '0'}My method returned false{/if}
```

However, doing this for methods **with dynamic parameters** that also return a string instead of a boolean seems to be impossible - eg (inside of a channel entries tag):

```
{if '{exp:my_plugin:my_method entry_id="{entry_id}"}' == 'blah'}My method returned the word blah{/if}
```

Interestingly, calling the plugin outside the conditional at least once in the same template makes the conditional work as expected:

```
test output: {exp:my_plugin:my_method entry_id="{entry_id}"}
{if '{exp:my_plugin:my_method entry_id="{entry_id}"}' == 'blah'}My method returned the word blah{/if}
```

... but this is obviously far too weird and fragile to be useful!

Wondering if I'm missing something obvious or making a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digital Surgeons appear to have made a plugin which works around this particular problem:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ifify

Answer (score 1):

Try by using parse="inward" parameter within the plugin tag like:

```
{if '{exp:my_plugin:my_method entry_id="{entry_id}" parse="inward"}' == 'blah'}My method returned the word blah{/if}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add an example to your answer to demonstrate what you mean, and what the parameter does (this would especially help new users who have not used that parameter before).

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately, though it could be due to already using parse="inward" on an outer Switchee tag.