# PHP string fun does not evaluate unless var is used elsewhere in template

Tags: conditionals, phpstringfun

I'm trying to use the PHP String fun plug-in to evaluate whether a current entry belongs to a specific channel and then show/hide a register prompt depending upon that. So I have a snippet:

```
{sn_content_channels_closed} = "content_guides|content_videos|content_white-papers"
```

Then the channel in question is "content_white-papers", however the template code below fails to return TRUE 'unless' I place the {channel_name} variable somewhere else in the template in addition to here:

```
{if '{exp:phpstringfun function="substr_count" par1="{channel_name}"}{sn_content_channels_closed}{/exp:phpstringfun}'=='1'}
```

Of course I could do that but I'd like to understand why this doesn't work, Parse order... EE WTF... something else?

Comment: Are you using this same tag with the same content and parameter somewhere else on the template?

Comment: Hi Robson, no it occurs just the once in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ugh, I came across what looks like the same thing a while ago: [plugin value in a template conditional](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/6053/plugin-value-in-a-template-conditional)

It's really odd. You could try ifify: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ifify

... though these days I think I'd attempt this more cleanly using Stash's `get_list` with `match` `against` parameters.

Comment: Thanks James, as I saw including the variable I'm testing elsewhere in the page causes the conditional to evaluate correctly but it's too fragile for my liking so I will definitely check out Ifify! :)